# Elasticsearch searching with perl client

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to do something that should be simple but I cannot get it to work.  I've looked and search all over to find detailed doc for perl search::elsticsearch.  I can only find CPAN doc and as far as search is concerned it is barely mentioned.  I've search here and cannot find a duplicate question.

I have elasticsearch and filebeat.  Filebeat is sending syslog to elasticsearch.  I just want to search for messages with matching text and date range.  I can find the messages but when I try to add date range the query fails.  Here is the query from kibana dev tools.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "term": { "message": "metrics" }},
        { "range": { "timestamp": { "gte": "now-15m" }}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get exactly what I'm looking for but there isn't an error.

Here is my attempt with perl

```
    my $results=$e->search(
        body => {
                query => {
                        bool => {
                         filter => {
                                        term => { message => 'metrics' },
                                        range => { timestamp => { 'gte' => 'now-15m' }}
                         }

                        }
                }
        }
);
```

This is the error.

```
[Request] ** [http://x.x.x.x:9200]-[400] 
[parsing_exception] 
[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME], 
with: {"col":69,"line":1}, called from sub Search::Elasticsearch::Role::Client::Direct::__ANON__ 
at ./elasticsearchTest.pl line 15. 
With vars: {'body' => {'status' => 400,'error' => {
'root_cause' => [{'col' => 69,'reason' => '[range] 
malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]',
'type' => 'parsing_exception','line' => 1}],'col' => 69,
'reason' => '[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]',
'type' => 'parsing_exception','line' => 1}},'request' => {'serialize' => 'std',
'path' => '/_search','ignore' => [],'mime_type' => 'application/json',
'body' => {
'query' => {
'bool' => 
{'filter' => {'range' => {'timestamp' => {'gte' => 'now-15m'}},
'term' => {'message' => 'metrics'}}}}},
'qs' => {},'method' => 'GET'},'status_code' => 400}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to search with the search::elasticsearch perl module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple filter clauses must be passed as separate JSON objects within an array (like in your initial JSON query), not multiple filters in the same JSON object. This maps to how you must create the Perl data structure.

```
filter => [
  {term => { message => 'metrics' }},
  {range => { timestamp => { 'gte' => 'now-15m' }}}
]
```

Comment: It worked.  Thank you for your help.  I now have a better understanding how the perl client is working.